# Sharing a link (share?url=) with spaces?

Tags: google-plus

Trying to add a sharing function to my site, but GPlus seems to have trouble sharing url's with spaces in them.

Even escaped they dont seem to work.
eg;
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.google.com/%23test%20test

It only seems to recognize upto before the %20.

Any ideas? Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

The site is rather ajaxy, and in the history tokens would be a pain to need to use non-standard escaping of characters just for google plus.

Comment: Could people downvoting please explain how I could have made my question better, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a bug with Google+ but rather its likely intentional because those URLs would need to be double URL encoded because one URL is sharing a second URL, thus your shared URL should be http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%2523test%2Btest

This won't work to create a preview in the share snippet but the URL is correct when it is shared.

All said, you shouldn't use spaces in your URLs because they are considered unsafe, see [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). You should change your app's URL structure.

Comment: I dont use spaces " " in my urls, but %20...is %20 really considered unsafe?
As mentioned, its an AJAX website, so those history tokens might contain, for example, a name or a short quote. "Thomas Wrobel" thus is "Thomas%20Wrobel"
Is that not correct?
If its not escaped too that, what should it be escaped too? "+" ?
Do I have to manually use my own escaping system to avoid spaces in my text even before using URLencode? That seems even more hack-jobish.

Comment: Additionally, double escaping does not work either.
Interesting GooglePlus actually fails to recognize "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%2523test%2Btest" as a url at all.

Comment: Like I said the preview won't work, but the URL is passed through correctly and that parts retained, see my test post: https://plus.google.com/101608135629412029753/posts/dGAJs39t4dY

Comment: oh, I apologize For some reason I thought you meant just the image preview. Yes, your right that style of link does work. I should be able to work with this.